Switchover of PolarDB compute nodes, Issue Promoting Replica Node to Primary Node in PostgreSQL Cluster
I am encountering an issue while trying to promote a replica node to a primary node in a PostgreSQL cluster. The promotion process fails unless the primary node is stopped first, leading to potential data corruption due to multiple nodes writing simultaneously. Here’s the detailed process and the error logs I encountered:
Steps to Reproduce:

Stop p1 primary

# 进入pb1容器  
docker exec -ti pb1 bash  
  
# 停止primary  
pg_ctl stop -m fast -D ~/primary  
  
日志如下:   
waiting for server to shut down.... done  
server stopped  


promote p2 replica

# 进入pb2容器  
docker exec -ti pb2 bash  
  
# promote replica  
pg_ctl promote -D ~/replica1  

The error is as follows:
[PFSD_SDK INF Dec 18 14:33:38.327335][859]pfsd_umount_force 247: pbdname nvme1n1  
[PFSD_SDK INF Dec 18 14:33:38.330154][859]chnl_connection_release_shm 1164: client umount return : deleted /var/run/pfsd//nvme1n1/859.pid  
[PFSD_SDK INF Dec 18 14:33:38.330163][859]pfsd_umount_force 261: umount success for nvme1n1  
waiting for server to promote...[PFSD_SDK INF Dec 18 14:33:38.444794][859]pfsd_umount_force 247: pbdname nvme1n1  
[PFSD_SDK INF Dec 18 14:33:38.446306][859]chnl_connection_release_shm 1164: client umount return : deleted /var/run/pfsd//nvme1n1/859.pid  
[PFSD_SDK INF Dec 18 14:33:38.446314][859]pfsd_umount_force 261: umount success for nvme1n1  
.[PFSD_SDK INF Dec 18 14:33:38.690673][859]pfsd_umount_force 247: pbdname nvme1n1  
[PFSD_SDK INF Dec 18 14:33:38.693022][859]chnl_connection_release_shm 1164: client umount return : deleted /var/run/pfsd//nvme1n1/859.pid  
[PFSD_SDK INF Dec 18 14:33:38.693035][859]pfsd_umount_force 261: umount success for nvme1n1  
[PFSD_SDK INF Dec 18 14:33:38.917831][859]pfsd_umount_force 247: pbdname nvme1n1  
[PFSD_SDK INF Dec 18 14:33:38.919652][859]chnl_connection_release_shm 1164: client umount return : deleted /var/run/pfsd//nvme1n1/859.pid  
[PFSD_SDK INF Dec 18 14:33:38.919664][859]pfsd_umount_force 261: umount success for nvme1n1  
[PFSD_SDK INF Dec 18 14:33:39.364163][859]pfsd_umount_force 247: pbdname nvme1n1  
[PFSD_SDK INF Dec 18 14:33:39.390100][859]chnl_connection_release_shm 1164: client umount return : deleted /var/run/pfsd//nvme1n1/859.pid  
[PFSD_SDK INF Dec 18 14:33:39.390109][859]pfsd_umount_force 261: umount success for nvme1n1  
 stopped waiting  
pg_ctl: server did not promote in time  

The database log is as follows:
$PGDATA/pg_log/postgresql-2024-12-18_142905_error.log  
  
849         2024-12-18 14:33:38.330 CST LOG:  received promote request  
849         2024-12-18 14:33:38.330 CST LOG:  async lock replay: startup@polar_alr_terminate_worker: terminate worker  
849         2024-12-18 14:33:38.333 CST LOG:  redo done at 0/484CAF88 system usage: CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 263.78 s  
849         2024-12-18 14:33:38.333 CST LOG:  last completed transaction was at log time 2024-12-18 14:29:14.656403+08  
849         2024-12-18 14:33:38.333 CST WARNING:  polar_log_read_record read records from 'currRecPtr: 0/484C5168, read record: (0/484C5168, 0/484C51E0), decoded record: (0/484C5168, 0/484C51E0, 0/0)' to 'currRecPtr: 0/484CAF88, read record: (0/484CAF88, 0/484CB000), decoded record: (0/484CAF88, 0/484CB000, 0/0)', next record is 'currRecPtr: 0/484CAF88, read record: (0/484CAF88, 0/484CB000), decoded record: (0/484CAF88, 0/484CB000, 0/0)'  
849         2024-12-18 14:33:38.380 CST WARNING:  replica can't modify file in shared storage by pfs: /nvme1n1/shared_data//base/5  
849         2024-12-18 14:33:38.424 CST WARNING:  replica can't modify file in shared storage by pfs: /nvme1n1/shared_data//base/1  
849         2024-12-18 14:33:38.465 CST WARNING:  replica can't modify file in shared storage by pfs: /nvme1n1/shared_data//base/4  
849         2024-12-18 14:33:38.509 CST WARNING:  replica can't modify file in shared storage by pfs: /nvme1n1/shared_data//base/13572  
849         2024-12-18 14:33:38.509 CST LOG:  selected new timeline ID: 2  
849         2024-12-18 14:33:38.511 CST LOG:  vfs_unlink /nvme1n1/shared_data//pg_wal/xlogtemp.849  
Got coredump signal(11) in process(849)  
Process Info:  
  pid:  849  
  type: startup  
  sql:  <NULL>  
Backtrace:  
  #0  polar_program_error_handler+0x388 [0xaaaad54f72a4]  
  #1  +0x388 [0xffffabc2d790]  
  #2  strerrordesc_np+0x1e30 [0xffffaac19950]  
  #3  dopr+0x164 [0xaaaad55824b0]  
  #4  pg_vsnprintf+0xa0 [0xaaaad5581c68]  
  #5  pvsnprintf+0x44 [0xaaaad5574e54]  
  #6  appendStringInfoVA+0xb4 [0xaaaad5576cb8]  
  #7  errmsg+0x1c4 [0xaaaad54ef674]  
  #8  polar_vfs_file_handle_node_type+0x158 [0xffffa77de3cc]  
  #9  polar_stat_file_before_hook+0x44 [0xffff933b5ef8]  
  #10 vfs_unlink+0xf0 [0xffffa77daa00]  
  #11 polar_unlink+0x4c [0xaaaad4e017bc]  
  #12 XLogFileCopy+0x130 [0xaaaad4e06f38]  
  #13 XLogInitNewTimeline+0xe4 [0xaaaad4e0acf4]  
  #14 StartupXLOG+0xcd0 [0xaaaad4e0bf68]  
  #15 StartupProcessMain+0xcc [0xaaaad51f49b4]  
  #16 AuxiliaryProcessMain+0x284 [0xaaaad51e2520]  
  #17 StartChildProcess+0x60 [0xaaaad51f27c0]  
  #18 PostmasterMain+0x1564 [0xaaaad51eb5bc]  
  #19 main+0x380 [0xaaaad50dde60]  
  #20 __libc_init_first+0x7c [0xffffaaba73fc]  
  #21 __libc_start_main+0x98 [0xffffaaba74cc]  
  #22 _start+0x30 [0xaaaad4cc1f70]  
851         2024-12-18 14:33:38.628 CST WARNING:  Failed to get the instance memory usage  
836         2024-12-18 14:33:39.049 CST LOG:  startup process (PID 849) was terminated by signal 11: Segmentation fault  
836         2024-12-18 14:33:39.049 CST LOG:  terminating any other active server processes  
836         2024-12-18 14:33:39.051 CST LOG:  shutting down due to startup process failure  
[PFSD_SDK INF Dec 18 14:33:39.051684][836]pfsd_umount_force 247: pbdname nvme1n1  
[PFSD_SDK INF Dec 18 14:33:39.072031][836]chnl_connection_release_shm 1164: client umount return : deleted /var/run/pfsd//nvme1n1/836.pid  
[PFSD_SDK INF Dec 18 14:33:39.072049][836]pfsd_umount_force 261: umount success for nvme1n1  
836         2024-12-18 14:33:39.072 CST LOG:  umount pbd nvme1n1 success  
836         2024-12-18 14:33:39.103 CST LOG:  database system is shut down  

The core file bt is as follows:
$ gdb --exec=/home/postgres/tmp_polardb_pg_15_base/bin/postgres --core=/home/postgres/replica1/core  
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 12.1-0ubuntu1~22.04.2) 12.1  
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.  
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>  
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.  
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.  
This GDB was configured as "aarch64-linux-gnu".  
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.  
For bug reporting instructions, please see:  
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.  
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:  
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.  
  
For help, type "help".  
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".  
  
warning: Can't open file /dev/zero (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing  
  
warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/PostgreSQL.3630676106 during file-backed mapping note processing  
  
warning: Can't open file /SYSV000c289a (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing  
[New LWP 849]  
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]  
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".  
Core was generated by `postgres(5432): startup                                                      '.  
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.  
#0  __pthread_kill_implementation (threadid=281473559998496, signo=signo@entry=11, no_tid=no_tid@entry=0) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:44  
44  ./nptl/pthread_kill.c: No such file or directory.  
(gdb) bt  
#0  __pthread_kill_implementation (threadid=281473559998496, signo=signo@entry=11, no_tid=no_tid@entry=0) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:44  
#1  0x0000ffffaabff254 in __pthread_kill_internal (signo=11, threadid=<optimized out>) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:78  
#2  0x0000ffffaabba67c in __GI_raise (sig=11) at ../sysdeps/posix/raise.c:26  
#3  0x0000aaaad54f74f0 in ?? ()  
#4  0x0000000b00000000 in ?? ()  
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)  

No oom or other errors were seen at the pb2 sudo dmesg system level. I tried shutting down other containers (to reduce memory usage), but the problem persisted.Is there any solution?
